# Передача пути к файлу, выбранного через input = file, через ajax

Tags: php, ajax, markdown

Проблема состоит в том, что я не могу передать временный путь к файлу, чтобы в дальнейшем, в скрипте-обработчике конвертировать его в markdown-текст.

**Код ajax-запроса:**

```
$('#md').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?=$dir?>/ajax/ajax_editor_md.php',
        data: {file: '<?=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/upload/pdfFiles/670.docx"?>'},
        success: function(result){
                $('#area').html(result);
                alert('ready');
                document.location.href = "<?=$_SERVER["SCRIPT_URI"]?>";
            }
        })
});
```

**Код php-обработчика:**

```
$converter = new Docx2md\Docx2md; 
$converter = $converter->parseFile($_REQUEST["file"]);
$markdown = $converter->markdown;

echo $markdown;
```

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: какие ошибки выдает ?

Comment: А чего вы хотите-то? Даже если предположить что `AJAX` рабочий, то: выполняется AJAX, передает файл, вы файл принимаете, делаете MARKDOWN, отдаете его и обновляете страницу, где все пусто (ибо файл пустой). ?)

Comment: @Manitikyl, Я получаю текст в формате markdown, передаю его в success и там же заполняю текстовое поле, в которое этот текст должен быть импортирован

Comment: @madfan41k, { success: false } при нажатии на кнопку

Comment: @ТигранАрустамов а в исходниках `url` какой?

Comment: @Manitikyl, в каком смысле в исходниках?

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем ответ, но попробуйте, во первых `file` поменять на `'file'`, а во вторых:

```
success: function(result){
                $('#area').html(result);
                alert('ready');
                document.location.href = "<?=$_SERVER["SCRIPT_URI"]?>";
            }
```

заменить на:

```
error:function(num) {
    alert(num);
},
status:function (number) {
    alert(number);
},
endstatus:function (number) {
    alert(number);
},
success: function(data){
    alert(data);
}
```

Так вы получите всю информацию, которую можно получить от `AJAX`, напишите нам, что Вы увидели и так нам будет проще разобраться что у вас за проблема.

Comment: Сейчас при нажатии мне возвращает {"success":true,"url":"\/kb\/\/"}

Comment: @ТигранАрустамов я наверное понял в чем у вас ошибка, а где находится сам файл `670.docx`? Если `site.ru/upload/pdfFiles/...` то замените `'<?=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/upload/pdfFiles/670.docx"?>'` на `'/upload/pdfFiles/670.docx'`. Должно получится так: `data: {'file': '/upload/pdfFiles/670.docx'},`

Comment: возвращается все то же {"success":true,"url":"\/kb\/\/"}. я думаю это у меня проблемы с url-адресами, потому что в url адресе после обновления страницы такой путь: site.ru/kb//40